# How to add cell without using indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` which loads a custom `collectionViewCell` every 7 cells. The problem with this is that it takes away from the content of the main array.

> (ie. if mainArray.count == 17 only 15 is displayed because indexPaths
>   have to be specified for the `customCollectionViewCells` being loaded.)

I don't want to use sections either. I was wondering if these was a way to load these cells without taking away from the main content?

**What I've tried**

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let counter == 0;
    if (index == 7 || index == 14) {
      counter = customCellsArray.count
     } 
    else{
      counter = mainArray.count
     }
    return counter;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your data source, return the number of cells you actually want, including the custom cells.  E.g.:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return customCellsArray.count + mainArray.count;
}
```

Then when you provide your cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
    cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if (indexPath.item % 7 == 0 && indexPath.item > 0) {
        // Return cell from customCellsArray.
    } else {
        // Return cell from mainCellsArray.
    }
}
```

You will have to map the `indexPath.item` to the proper index you need in your two arrays.

Comment: `fatal error array index out of range`(on  mainArray ) is thrown each time collectionView reaches last cell.

Comment: Okay, well, you need to debug that.  What is the index?  What is the size of the array?  How are you calculating the index?  There is probably a bug there.  Set a breakpoint where you calculate it and see what's going on.  Or post more code, or consider opening a new question with the code you have now.